# How can I cache dependency installations in CircleCI 2.0

Tags: caching, circleci

I have a nodejs app and I'm already caching the node_modules folder based on the package.json checksum. My `test` job steps involves 1) installing python-pip and using pip to install awscli, and 2) installing some dependencies for the popular wait-for-it.sh. My `deployment` job steps include 1) installing python-pip and using pip to install awscli.

Since 1) and 2) don't change, and since I need 1) in both `test` and `deployment`, how can I properly cache these steps? What should I enter for `key` and `paths` with `save_cache`, and how should I use `restore_cache`? This doesn't appear to exactly follow the same pattern as the node_modules caching.

Comment: One approach to consider is to create a custom Docker image that has Python/Pip/awscli pre-installed.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Hey Oliver, how would that look if I have several other images as well? As in: `test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.9.1
      - image: circleci/mongo:3.2.13
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6
      - image: rabbitmq:3.5.4`